# Can we add Date range in Group by search filters in Openerp 7.0?

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP 7 Is it possible to add From and To date in "Group By Filter" ?.. if possible please give me steps how to add in group by filter date range

Answer (score 0):

import time
import netsvc
from osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMATS_MAP, float_compare

class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

```
_columns = {
    'order_date_from':fields.function(lambda *a,**k:{}, method=True, type='date',string="Order date from"),
    'order_date_to':fields.function(lambda *a,**k:{}, method=True, type='date',string="Order date to"),

}
```

sale_order()

Here I've given the ex for 'Order Date' in Sale Order module. Try the codes. Hope it will solve ur problem.

```
<record id="sale_order_period_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.period.filter</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_sales_order_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="after">
            <field name="order_date_from" filter_domain="[('date_order','&gt;=',self)]" widget="calendar"/>
            <field name="order_date_to" filter_domain="[('date_order','&lt;=',self)]" widget="calendar"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks Waran but its not working with "Group By" search filter

Answer (score 0):

You can define group by filter in xml.

```
<filter string="Month" name="groupbymonth" icon="terp-personal" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'visitdate'}" />
```

Domain looks like,

```
domain="[('visitdate', '&gt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d 00:00:00')),('visitdate', '&lt;=', time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d 23:59:59'))]"
```

You need to add domain like given above into the group by filter,
this is the example, you need to change it to your requirement.

I hope this helps you.